# Should I add more protein to my diet to avoid muscle loss?

Tags: diet, muscle, protein

I've read several places you should try to at least get `.5` g of protein per pound of weight. Note that I don't know my lean weight. Now I'm a `186 cm(~6 feet)` tall male weighing `111.8 kg(~246 lbs)`, which means I should be eating `246 / 2 = 123 g` of protein per day. However, currently my average protein intake is around `70 - 80 g` per day.

Does this mean mean I should try to get more protein in my diet, and is there a chance my muscles are/could be taking damage? I'm a naturally strong person, and haven't felt any problems so far, however, I just recently started eating healthier, and I want to avoid any ill effects of doing so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.5g protein per pound weight is for sedentary individuals to maintain muscle mass.  Losing muscle mass is not necessarily a fast process, but there are ill effects over time.  If you are exercising, you will need more protein.

I would increase your protein intake.  It has a double advantage of being more satiating (allowing less room for junk food) and having a higher thermic effect--i.e. it burns more calories to process.

Comment: What's the easiest way to add more protein in a natural way? Meat or cheese?

Comment: Can't edit the comment, but it was a bit misleading, I meant, meat, cheese or something else? I'm not doing a strict diet, and I'm keeping well below my RDI, without going hungry, so just looking for a good natural source.

Comment: Meat, cheese, eggs are all good sources. Its best to mix it up and vary it rather than just focus on one source.

Comment: Don't forget milk, chicken and all kind of fishes. It's the easy way to increase protein intake without eating unnecessary fat. Most fishes have healthy fats (poly-unsaturated).